# c# add or read from an c# exe file

Tags: c#

Is it possible to open a c# exe file (console app) from another c # project (windows form) and to write or read different text values from the exe file? i'm using user32dll to handle the exe file.

Thx
I did use this method to add a text in an exe file:

```
        Clipboard.SetText("Message!");
        foreach (IntPtr pPost in pControls)
        {
            PostMessage(pPost, (uint)WindowMessage.WM_PASTE, 0, 0);
        }
```

but is not working. I don't see the "Message" post added in c# exe (which is a console app) . Thoug using the notepad.exe everyting is working ok.

Comment: can you elaborate on these dates? What dates are they? Are they variables? Also, I don't really think you need `user32.ddl` to write to the exe?

Comment: string values. I would like to read and write text values in the exe file

Comment: so you want to just read/write dates into the exe file? You want to append these to the exe?

Comment: Are you trying to run the exe and get data from the output? Or do you want to _change_ the exe itself?

Comment: i want to open it and to read and write in it (of course from another c# application).

Comment: @dina - So, you want to change the binary itself? Not run it? Your example seems to suggest you want to send information _to_ a running executable and retrieve the results.

Comment: yes. this is what i want to do

Comment: so i run an exe file using  process.Start. Secondly i want to write or read in that exe file

Comment: @dina - Changing the `exe` may well mean it can't run anymore. Can you explain _exactly_ what you mean by "write or read in that exe file"?

Comment: using the process.start() i did open the notepad.exe file. I write in it the message "Message!". It is working. The problem is i can;t do the same if i open a c# console app exe.Using process.start() i've open the c# .exe file, but  I don't see the "Message" posted in the running executable: a console ap. Why? Do i have some restriction when writting in c# exe files?

Comment: @dina - Using `process.Start()` did **not** open the exe. It _executed_ it. When you say `open` a file, this would be like opening a text file in notepad or a word document in word. Please use the correct terms, or people will get confused as to what you are really trying to do.

Comment: ok. thx for correcting me. Is there a way i could write or read values from a exe file that is executed?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class to execute the command line app and redirect the input/output using the [`StandardInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) and [`StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) properties.

From MSDN:

```
 Process p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

There are more examples on the `StandardOutput` page linked above.

Comment: +1 did not know you could do this! =) But this would cover sending inputs TO the calling exe FROM the executed exe? right?

Comment: @giddy - You can also redirect `StandardInput` and `StandardError`.

Comment: OK checked MSDN, seems you can do just the _opposite_ for standard input! Nice, learn't something new today!

Comment: @elisa - Your question doesn't make sense. An exe file contains binary code. Why would you want to read that?

Answer (score 2):

There are a large number of possible failure modes here.

- First off, WM_PASTE is sent, not posted, you should use SendMessage().
- Only a limited number of Windows controls actually implement behavior for this message, it has to be a edit control, rich edit control or combo box.
- There's UIPI, the user interface part of UAC, it stops an unelevated process from hijacking the privileges of an elevated one.
- There's the usefulness of doing something like this, pasting text in *every* child window doesn't make much sense.
- The pinvoke declaration you used for PostMessage() isn't correct, the wparam and lparam arguments are IntPtr, not int.

Visit pinvoke.net for (usually) correct pinvoke declarations.