# open exe - FindWindowsEX

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I am running an application that has the ability to process a exe file.Using process.start() and FindWindowsEx() I run the exe and send a PostMessage() to it.

My exe file is a form application. If i have multiple textboxes in my exe file and if i would like to populate just one of these text boxes with a message what should i do?

```
 pControl = FindWindowEx(pWnd, IntPtr.Zero, infoChild.EditFieldName, IntPtr.Zero);
        while (pControl != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            pControls.Add(pControl);
            pControl = FindWindowEx(pWnd, pControl, infoChild.EditFieldName, IntPtr.Zero);


        }

       Clipboard.SetText("Message!");
       foreach (IntPtr pPost in pControls)
        {
        { PostMessage(pPost, (uint)WindowMessage.WM_PASTE, 0, 0); }
        }
//the codei've posted automatically populates all the textboxes from my form with "Message!"
```

thx for advice

Comment: Is the "exe" your own, so that you can make changes to it?

Comment: why? i just want to add values in exe using another application with the help of specific contros

Comment: The trick is to know which one of the text boxes? Or are you happy with anyone of them???

Comment: I see.Ok...I did the exe file, The form application is created by me. The name of the textbox that i would like to access if textbox2 , the method is  private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        } THX danbystrom

Comment: what is the trick? how can i add the teext value in just one textbox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# add or read from an c# exe file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523210/c-add-or-read-from-an-c-exe-file)

Comment: Brr, you're high-maintenance asking the same question over and over again using different user names.  And learning *nothing* from the posted answers.

Comment: @elisa: I've merged **several** of your accounts together.  [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562#44562)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot access the names of your controls using these techniques. What I would do, is to override the WndProc method in you exe's form and have it respond to the WM_USER message and have it return the window handle of the textbox that you want to communicate with.

Then you should use SendMessage/WM_SETTEXT to set the text in the textbox using that handle. An app that destroys the content of the Clipboard without prior warning to the user should be banishied from all known and unknown universes!