# How can I run a console application before running my game?

Tags: c#, console

What I want to do is run a console application, have the user input some details, then pass the user input to my game.

I want the user to specify the resolution of the game, to be put into PreferredBackBuffer.

Is this possible? I know I can write a settings file and read from that, but I'd rather just cut that part out and do it directly.

Here is the "game" I have. I left out Player.cs as I don't think it's imperative to show for the sake of my question.

Main.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;  
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace SimplePlayer
{
    public class Main : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
    const string fileName = "AppSettings.dat";

    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D spaceTexture;
    Player playerShip;

    public Main()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        ReadRes();
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        spaceTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("spaceBackground");
        Texture2D playerTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("shipSprite");
        playerShip = new Player(GraphicsDevice, new Vector2(400, 300), playerTexture);

    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
           this.Exit();

        playerShip.Update(gameTime);

        UpdateInput();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    private void UpdateInput()
    {
        KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
        GamePadState gamePadState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || gamePadState.DPad.Up == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            playerShip.Accelerate();
        }

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || gamePadState.DPad.Down == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            playerShip.MoveReverse();
        }

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || gamePadState.DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            playerShip.StrafeLeft();
        }

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || gamePadState.DPad.Right == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            playerShip.StrafeRight();
        }
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(spaceTexture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        playerShip.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

        public void SetWindowSize(int x, int y)
        {
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = x;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = y;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace SimplePlayer
{
#if WINDOWS
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Main game = new Main())
            {
                game.Run();
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Why can't you have the user to set that at the game's loading screen?

Comment: Have you run across something that suggests you can't write a console application which requests data and then launches another program and passes it that data?

Comment: Having your users type in the settings for the game each time they run it seems a bit user unfriendly.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but if I'm gonna play your game, I only want to have to tell it how to run once (during install or first time run). It shouldn't bother me with that again. If you want them to be able to change it later, provide an in-game configuration screen.

Comment: Well, I'm doing this as an exercise for myself, just to find out if such a thing is possible. I've just started learning to program and am not doing anything serious yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your game executable could really just be an executable to the console application. When the use is done entering his preferences, your console application can execute your game, passing in the preferences as command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to start up an executable in code:

```
const string ex1 = "C:\\";
const string ex2 = "C:\\SomeDirectory";

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "YourGame.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + ex1 + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + ex2;

try
{
    // Start the process
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
    }
}
catch
{
    // Log error.
}
```

Comment: I added source code to my question. Would it be possible to edit Program.cs to run a console application, then pass the variables inputted by the user to the game with game.Run()?

Comment: My suggestion was that you create two separate projects. One project is your game which should compile into a executable file called SimplePlayer.exe in you Debug/Release folder.

Comment: I know I can do that, but is it possible to do the way I desire to?

Comment: Is SimplePlayer a Console Application? If so then you should be able to do Console.WriteLine() and Console.ReadLine() to get the input from the user

Comment: No, SimplePlayer is an XNA game. What I want to do is bring up a console application before I start the game, have the user input two numbers (the screen resolution), then pass the numbers to the game program in order to set the PreferredBackBuffer/screen resolution. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. I found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523210/c-sharp-add-or-read-from-an-c-sharp-exe-file

This will allow you to redirect the standard input/output to that console application and then read the input with Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()